# BarChart Graphic in PrimeFaces are not Displayed JSF 2.2

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

i am using primefaces 4.0 and i am trying to do a Bar-chart, the code compile without error but the chart is not showing in the generate page.

Managed Bean:

```
package per.vmonsanto.controladores;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.CartesianChartModel;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.ChartSeries;
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DashBoardBean {
private CartesianChartModel categoryModel;
/**
 * Creates a new instance of DashBoardBean
 */
public DashBoardBean() {
     createCategoryModel();

}

 public CartesianChartModel getCategoryModel() {  
    return categoryModel;  
}  

private void createCategoryModel() {  
    categoryModel = new CartesianChartModel();  
    ChartSeries from = new ChartSeries();  
    from.setLabel("Formularios");  

    from.set("2010", 256);  
    from.set("2011", 264);  
    from.set("2012", 345);  
    from.set("2013", 334);  
    from.set("2014", 143);  

    ChartSeries users = new ChartSeries();  
    users.setLabel("Usuarios");  

    users.set("2010", 288);  
    users.set("2011", 326);  
    users.set("2012", 318);  
    users.set("2013", 345);  
    users.set("2014", 290);  

    categoryModel.addSeries(users);  
    categoryModel.addSeries(from);  
  }  

}
```

This is the xhtml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
     <ui:define name="tittle"> Pagina Principal</ui:define>  

    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="resources/template/masterLayout.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="menu">
                <ul class="section menu">
                    <li><a class="menuitem">Menu 1</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a>Submenu 1</a> </li>
                            <li><a>Submenu 2</a> </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>                    
                </ul>

            </ui:define>   
            <ui:define name="main">
                <div class="grid_10">
                    <div class="box round first">
                        <h2>Grafico</h2>
                        <div class="block">
                            <p:barChart id="basic" value="#{dashBoardBean.categoryModel}" legendPosition="ne" 
                                        title="Formulario/Usuario" min="0" max="200" style="height:300px"/>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box round">
                        <h2>
                            Estadisticas</h2>
                        <div class="block">
                            <div class="stat-col">
                                <span>Formularios Creados</span>
                                <p class="purple">
                                    70</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="stat-col">
                                <span>Formularios Digitados</span>
                                <p class="yellow">
                                    32,729</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="stat-col">
                                <span>Formularios Por Dia</span>
                                <p class="green">
                                    1669</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="stat-col">
                                <span>Usuarios</span>
                                <p class="blue">
                                    438</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="stat-col">
                                <span>Usuarios Activos</span>
                                <p class="red">
                                    228</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="stat-col">
                                <span>Formulario/Usuario</span>
                                <p class="purple">
                                    <img src="img/icon-direction.png" alt="" />&nbsp;234</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="stat-col last">
                                <span>Total</span>
                                <p class="darkblue">
                                    70,000</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </ui:define>


        </ui:composition>


    </h:body>



    </html>
```

And this a relevant seccion of the Generated Source

HEAD:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/WebMultiFormBackend/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-aristo" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/WebMultiFormBackend/faces/javax.faces.resource/charts/charts.css?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/WebMultiFormBackend/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/WebMultiFormBackend/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/WebMultiFormBackend/faces/javax.faces.resource/charts/charts.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script>
```

Chart Part:

```
 <div class="block"><div id="basic" style="height:300px"></div><script id="basic_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('BarChart','widget_basic',{id:'basic',data:[[288,326,318,345,290],[256,264,345,334,143]],categories:['2010','2011','2012','2013','2014'],title:'Formulario\/Usuario',legendPosition:'ne',axes:{xaxis:{label:'',angle:0},yaxis:{label:'',angle:0}},series:[{label:'Usuarios'},{label:'Formularios'}],orientation:'vertical',barPadding:8,barMargin:10,datatip:true,min:0.0,max:200.0},'charts');});</script>  
                        </div>
```

Comment: Can you put the xhtml code complete?

Comment: xhtml have being updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the xmlns and put inside div a primefaces panel. I think this is a bug.

For instance, try this. It's work to me.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
       xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      >
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
<div>
   <p:panel>
                  <p:barChart id="basic" value="#{dashBoardBean.categoryModel}" legendPosition="ne" 
                                        title="FormularioUsuario" min="0" max="200" style="height:300px"/>
                                        </p:panel>
</div>                                        
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That Work for me, thanks a lot. Just add <p:panel> tags and work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing in this topic because many of you will came here to find your solution about rendering Primefaces Charts. So:

-BEFORE starting implementing any suggestions

*** make an inspection first (if you are using Chrome for example - right click -> inspect -> console), so to be sure that the problem comes from the scope you are searching.

- Many times the problem that many elements not rendering or jsf not working properly is that something before render generates a problem - maybe a false call of a command. With inspection you will have a better view.