# Primefaces imports, cannot be resolved

Tags: java, primefaces, import, bar-chart

Hi I am trying to draw a bar chart with primefaces.

When I import below lines to my chart file,

```
import org.primefaces.model.chart.BarChartModel;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.ChartSeries;
```

it gives error in first import saying that:

> `The import org.primefaces.model.chart.BarChartModel cannot be resolved`

But it doesn't give error in second import. What am I doing wrong and how should I solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Primefaces 5 to use the BarChartModel. I expect you use 4, where you should use a CartesianChartModel. For example as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646646/barchart-graphic-in-primefaces-are-not-displayed-jsf-2-2).